# Simple 'C' questions for environmental physics code

Tags: c

I'm very new to 'c' and am trying to get some code to work. The code takes in an input file with:

year month date hour minute PAR

It then prints out computations on the screen I believe.

Q1: Where do I edit the code (ie. replace filename with the actual name of my input file?

```
    FILE *in_file;

while((c=getopt(argc, argv, "f:"))!=-1)
 switch(c) {
 case 'f':
    strcpy(filename, optarg);
    break;
 }

in_file=fopen(filename,"r");

while (fscanf(in_file, "%d%d%d%d%d%lf\n", &year, &month, &date, &hour, &minute, &par )>0){
```

Q2: Am I right to assume that the input file is an ascii file with 6 columns separated by a single space?

Q3: I've tried to compile the code using g++ w/ redhat after playing around a bit but always get this error:

28:33: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
 void main(int argc, char *argv[]){

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. The entire code is available at:

[DiffuseRadiation.c](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2010spring/geog/595/001/www/diffuseradiation.c)

Comment: One question per question please. Clue's in the name. Your Q3 in particular seems fairly self-explanatory?? You have `void main` which is wrong because it's supposed to be `int main` so simply make it `int main`? Which C book are you using? And why is this post tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: There's no "replace filename" step -- this code expects the filename as a command-line parameter. In particular, as `-f filename.ext`

Comment: Apologies for the multiple questions (first-time poster). I very much appreciate the help and will use better form in the future.

Comment: The format of your error message suggest that you are using a C++ compiler. Yet you claim that the question is about C. So, is it C or C++?

Comment: You compile `C` with `gcc`, you compile `C++` with `g++`.

Answer (score 5):

Q1: Pass your actual input file path as command line parameter

Q2: Who can know that? But that code seems to assume so.

Q3: Define your main function as

```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// ^^^
     // ...
   }
```

to get rid of that error.

---

<sub>Usually you can ask exactly one question per question, and there are pretty good reasons for this. Feel lucky that your questions were answered here. Don't wonder if your question might be downvoted and removed.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Q2: According to the `fscanf` format string, your data will be read from the file in batches of 6 values (5 integers and 1 floating-point) separated by whitespace. There's absolutely no requirement for these values to be organized in columns or "nicely" formatted in any other way. The file will be seen by `fscanf` as a linear stream (a tape) of values separated by whitespace. Whitespace includes spaces, tabs, newline characters. I.e. `fscanf` does not care how your stream of values is split into the physical file lines. You can format the input file as a huge single line of values, or you can chop it up into lines in any way you please.

BTW, the `\n` at the end of that format string is redundant and achieves nothing at all. `"%d%d%d%d%d%lf"` would work the same.

Also

```
fscanf(in_file, "%d%d%d%d%d%lf\n", &year, &month, &date, &hour, &minute, &par ) > 0
```

is a rather dangerous success condition. If at least one, but less than six values are read from the file, it will treat it as a successful read. However, the unread variables will simply retain their original values, producing a generally meaningless combination. This

```
fscanf(in_file, "%d%d%d%d%d%lf\n", &year, &month, &date, &hour, &minute, &par ) == 6
```

would make more sense as a success condition.

Q3: As the compiler has already told you, `main` must be declared as returning `int`. `void main` is illegal.

P.S. Another minor nitpick: `%lf` format in `printf` became legal in C99. So, from the pedantic point of view this code requires a C99 (or later) compiler, even though it appears to be written for "old" C compilers in all other respects.